# How to make text file created in Ubuntu compatible with Windows Notepad?

Tags: text-editor

Sometime I have to use the text files created in Ubuntu, using editors, in Windows editors. So basically when ever I create a text file in Ubuntu I append the extension `.txt`, and it does make the file open in Windows very easily.

But the actual problem is the text files created in Ubuntu are so difficult to understand (read) when opened in Windows' Notepad. No matter how many lines have been used, all the lines appear in the same one line.

Is there a easy way to save the text files in Ubuntu's basic editors so that it can be seen exactly the same in Windows' notepad?

Comment: If you're open to alternatives, I'd recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), a free source code editor with syntax highlighting and more. It handles standard Unix file endings perfectly and offers a conversion function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unlike Unix where a new line is represented by a LF character we need a combination CR/LF for files in DOS/Windows:

#### Gedit

We can let Gedit save text documents with Windows-style line endings in the *File -> Save as* dialog.

- Adjust the settings for *Line Endings* in the drop down menu to **Windows**.

  [image]

#### Nano

To make nano write text files in DOS format we have to run it with the following command line option <sup>[1](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v1.2/nano.html)</sup>:

```
nano --dos <filename>
```

#### Vim

Vim can convert files from Unix to DOS format with the following control sequences  <sup>[2](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format)</sup> :

```
:update
:e ++ff=dos
:w
```

#### Emacs

To set the buffer coding to DOS style issue <kbd>Meta</kbd> +  <kbd>x</kbd> :

```
set-buffer-file-coding-system utf-8-dos
```

Comment: Thanks Takkat for your answer. I'm in Office and currently using Windows(no Ubuntu installed). I'll let you know as soon as I reach my home. :)

Comment: It would be this much simple I didn't expect. Yes it worked for `gedit`. Do you know how to achieve it for other editors like `nano`, `vi` and `Emacs`. I'm accepting this answer in a hope you'll find a way and make this question complete and perfect. Thanks.. :)

Comment: That's brilliant.  Thanks for asking the question and thanks @Takkat for your answer.  I will use this a lot!

Answer (score 8):

## Converting Unix-style line termination to Windows-style and back

I'm not sure if it's installed by default. Try this to be sure

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

You can convert the files with this to Windows-style

```
unix2dos myFileFromUbuntu.txt
```

And with this back to Unix-style

```
dos2unix myFileFromWindows.txt
```

Changing them back is often unnecessary. You will find, that the standard text editors handle Windows-style line termination just fine.

Comment: Good!! +1 for alternate way.. :)

Comment: A bit overkill I would say...

Comment: "Write programs that do one thing and do it well." - Doug McIllroy about the Unix philosophy

Comment: @Dualinity Not an overkill if you have many files to convert