# How to get external IP from remote Ubuntu computer

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-access, ip, rdp

My ISP typically leaves my IP address fixed, but when there is a power failure, or if their service goes down for more than about 15-30 minutes, my home is assigned a different IP address.

My goal is to be able to connect to my home Ubuntu computer using my laptop running Win-8 RDP.  I do NOT want to run a Dynamic IP service and prefer connecting directly to the IP address.

My question is "How do I get my home IP address when I am away remotely?"

(solution follows)

Comment: There is no way if you do not have a static IP or a dynamic IP service.

Comment: Where there is a will, there is a way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I made was to use Cron and DropBox to share my IP address.

I wrote a bash program.  (See image) (sorry, I don't know how to share the script)

[image: Bash Script: showmyip]

I copied this into "/etc/cron.hourly/showmyip"

Now, every hour, I get an updated file copied to my DropBox folder that shows my IP address.  I can access it from any location or computer by just checking my DropBox folder.  It looks like this:

[image]

The reason I created an HTML file is that when I was testing it, I used multiple lines.  In Windows, all the lines merged into one. It's a little more complex than it needs to be, but it works.  It does what I need.

I originally set it to update every day, but decided to update every 10 minutes.  That way, if it changes, I pretty much have instant access to the new IP.

Another nice thing about doing it this way is that no one else has access to the account.

Comment: Well, this is your own dynamic IP service. ))

Comment: Why every 10 minutes? If you drop a suitable script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`, you can run it every time your IP changes (or the interface go up and down). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/436943/how-to-run-a-script-when-there-is-a-change-in-your-local-ip

Comment: BTW, the fact that the "lines merged into one" is due to the [different line ending between windows and unix](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376404/how-to-make-text-file-created-in-ubuntu-compatible-with-windows-notepad). About formatting code, please read http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Rmano, I was unaware of the dispatcher.d, but thank you, that is good to know.  Also I was aware of "why" the lines merged, but not how to fix it. the HTML option works so I won't change it now.  But thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Pilot6, Yes, LOL thanks. I already use Drop box so I don't have to pay for a service.

Comment: @Rmano, about the Dispatcher.d, does that only activate if the computer's IP changes or if my Internet IP changes?

Comment: Even if in principle is possible, I never saw the external IP change if there is no disconnection. At least there should be a modem disconnection, which will trigger an up/down to you machine. But I am not 100% sure of this.

Comment: My computer has a fixed IP address so it would never change.  The router also has the same IP address reserved for my mac address.  So that address would never change even if the router were replaced. That's what got me to thinking that dispatcher.d would never work.  It would never see my IP address change.